# Two forms working with the same Boolean

Tags: c#, boolean, settings

To make it short:

Forms A and B need to work with a Boolean in the project settings: "booly".

When a button is pressed in the form A, the variable "booly" is set to true.

Then form B will show up, and while it's closing, it's supposed to set the Boolean to false, but I'm having trouble making this work. For form A it works just fine, but form B is not changing the variable. Here's the code for form B:

```
bool booly = Properties.Settings.Default.booly;

private void formB_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
      booly = false;
}
```

Comment: Is your bool global? Does it throw a compile error when you try and set it from form B? What do you mean it doesn't set it? Are you using Visual Studio? Does it tell you that it can access it? There could be at least 100 reasons. Need more detail kimosabi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it is not working is because you are setting the `Form2.booly` **instance** to false and not the `Properties.Settings...`. It would be worth mentioning that `booly` is **NOT** a pointer to `Properties.Settings.Default.booly` if you have come from C++ so you should change your method to this.

```
private void formB_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.booly = false;
}
```

A simple example / way of testing this would be:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    bool valueA = true;
    bool valueB = valueA;

    // Both will print TRUE
    Console.WriteLine("ValueA is: " + valueA.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("ValueB is: " + valueB.ToString());

    // Change valueA but leave valueB unchanged
    valueA = false;

    // valueA now FALSE while valueB is still TRUE
    Console.WriteLine("ValueA is: " + valueA.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("ValueB is: " + valueB.ToString());
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

So the final output of the code-snippet would be:

```
Value A is: True
Value B is: True
Value A is: False
Value B is: True
```